# SQLite - order by numbers inside string

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, sql-order-by

its my first post here, so bear with me.

I'm trying to order a query by numbers in a specific row that contain letters, using SQLite.

Example: "Winter 1993".

I want to be able to sort by the numbers only, without altering the table structure.

My query:

```
select Col from table order by Col*1, Col Asc
```

The query sorts by letters first and then by numbers, I just want it sorted by numbers.

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Comment: It really depends on how the numbers are formatted into the string you want to order on, but you'll find that trying to extract and order on a number in a string is not very efficient which is why you really should store the numerical data separately if you need to query on it.

Comment: Can you share some more data? Are they all of the form "Winter <four digit year>"?

Comment: @Mureinik Its 4, Winter, Summer, Fall, spring, then its years. So it would be "{Season} {Year}"

Comment: @juharr I agree, the problem is I can't alter the table in anyway. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it would be `{Season} {Year}`

If the numbers are consistently located after the first space in the string, we can use string functions to extract them as follows:

```
select col
from mytable
order by substr(col, instr(col, ' ') + 1) + 0, col
```